# How to modifying child component's slots from parent components in Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am developing a `DataTable` component in Svelte with this usage:

```
<script>
    import DataTable from './DataTable.svelte'
    import Column from './Column.svelte'
    
    let items = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Name 1', age: 23},
        {id: 2, name: 'Name 2', age: 28},
        {id: 3, name: 'Name 3', age: 35},
        {id: 4, name: 'Name 4', age: 18},
    ] 
</script>

<DataTable {items} let:item>
        <Column title="Id">{item.id}</Column>
        <Column title="Customer">{item.name}</Column>
        <Column title="Age">{item.age}</Column>
</DataTable>
```

The `Column` component just works as a meta definition for `DataTable` component. There are some other ways to define `columns` in `script` section (like [this](https://github.com/dasDaniel/svelte-table)), but in order to be more focused on business logic in `script` section, I'm trying to reduce component's visual definitions/configurations in the `script` section.

Therefore, the default `slot` content in `Column` component should be passed to parent `DataTable` component and then rendered in the cells. In other words, parent component should take control of child component's slots.

**DataTable.svelte:**

```
<script>
    import { setContext, getContext, onDestroy } from 'svelte';
    
    export let items = []
    
    let columns = []
    
    setContext('columns', {
        register: column => {
            columns.push(column)
            
            onDestroy(() => {
                const i = columns.indexOf(column)
                columns.splice(i, 1)
            })
        },
        getColumns: () => {return columns}
    })
</script>
<slot />
{#if items}
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {#each columns as column}
                    <th>
                        {column.title}
                    </th>
                {/each}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {#each items as item1, i}
            <tr>
                {#each columns as column}
                    <td>
                        {JSON.stringify(column.$$scope.ctx[0][i])}
                    </td>
                {/each}
            </tr>
        {/each}
    </table>
{/if}
```

**Column.svelte:**

```
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';
    let columnProps = {...$$props}
    const { register } = getContext('columns')
    register(columnProps) 
</script>
```

[Here is the repl.](https://svelte.dev/repl/f4c4692e4a704f23ab9851d3b952b71d?version=3.47.0)

In this line: `{JSON.stringify(column.$$scope.ctx[0][i])}` the bound row is shown correctly (not sure if it works in all cases because index 0 is hardcoded!).

But, the content should be rendered using the first, second, etc. column's slots (`{item.id}`,`{item.name}`, etc.)

How can I render slot dynamically or in the parent component to show the correct slot content?

Also, as slot value passed to `Column` in the above usage (without any slot inside the child), Svelte raises warning `(<Column> received an unexpected slot "default".)` which is completely correct!

What is the correct way of implementing this `DataTable` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is probably to not do it like this at all. I worked on implementing a tab control in a similar fashion and Svelte seems to be not so great at interacting with slots/child components that are used in multiple places.

To make this work to some degree you can apply a few changes:

1. Render the cells in `Column`:

```html
<td>
    <slot />
</td>
```

2. Render the entire row by inserting the slot in `DataTable` (it already contains all columns):

```html
{#each items as item, i}
    <tr>
        <slot {item} />
    </tr>
{/each}
```

3. Remove that rogue `<slot/>` in `DataTable` after the `<script>` tag which will break since it has no `item`.
4. Reassign `columns`, since it won't update otherwise; also check whether the column has been registered yet, otherwise you get duplicates (one for each row):

```js
    register: column => {
        if (columns.find(c => c.title == column.title))
            return;

        columns = [...columns, column];
        
        onDestroy(() => {
            columns = columns.filter(c => c.title != column.title);
        })
    },
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ab49bb29d7994ebead72fd2efb14b04a?version=3.47.0)

You will probably regret this once you figure that the `title` should be arbitrary DOM content and not just a string.

---

You should definitely not access something like `$$scope.ctx`, that is an implementation detail that can change at any point.