# React Components to SvelteKit - Objects with HTML in attribute (JSX rendering) to Script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, svelte, sveltekit

Since I'm changing a React project to SvelteKit, I've got a specific situation that made me a lot curious about it.

Let's suppose that I do have a component in React that receives the object `columnsMockExample` as props, for example, and consumes an HTML inside of the object, as:

```
const columnsMockExample = [{name: 'Column 1', html: '<div>Inner HTML example</div>' }]
<ColumnsComponent columnsProp={columnsMockExample}/>
```

So, in React, we could map this object to consume it and show every `.html` inside of `columnsMockExample`:

`{props.columnsProp.map((columnFromMockExample) => columnFromMockExample.html)};`

So then, here is the question: as SvelteKit has the `<script/>` tag apart from the HTML, how can I create my object `columnsMockExample` inside of the SvelteKit`<script/>` tag since it is not JSX?

*wrong SvelteKit script example is written below:*

```
<script> 
  const columnsMockExample = [{name: 'Column 1', html: '<div>Inner HTML example</div>' }] 
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different approaches that can be taken here, all of which are a bit different.

1. Use slots to make each column render a cell and render entire rows via the parent components slot. Example can be seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070779/how-to-modifying-child-components-slots-from-parent-components-in-svelte).
2. Define separate components and instead of passing HTML, you pass the component class. As of now this is a bit of a pain, because components cannot be defined in the same file. [REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/212b982644914226a7f2d67b7c8f911c?version=3.48.0)

   The key is to render the components dynamically via `<svelte:component />` and pass in the current column value as a well-known prop that is the same for all cell components.
3. Instead of using components actually render HTML directly using `{@html}`. I do **absolutely not** recommend this, because it makes it easy to create XSS vulnerabilities. [REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/13b6e62dcf984bea99374b9bf435eecd?version=3.48.0)

   The key here is to provide the content as a function of the column value, like this:

   ```js
    const columns = [
        { key: 'name', html: value => `<button>${value}</button>` },
        { key: 'age', html: value => `<em>${value}</em>` },
    ]
   ```

   So this can be rendered with the current value like this:

   ```html
   <td>{@html column.html(value)}</td>
   ```

   If you only have static content, you do not need a function of course.
4. Use slots and keys to render the different cells. This is a very flexible approach which is used e.g. by the `DataTable` of the [Carbon Svelte components](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-svelte).

   The columns define the key, and the cells can be templated via slots and slot props.

   E.g.

   ```html
   <!-- DataTable.svelte -->
    <script>
        export let columns;
        export let rows;
    </script>

    <table>
        {#each rows as row}
            <tr>
                {#each columns as column}
                    {@const value = row[column.key]}
                    <td>
                        <slot {value} key={column.key} />
                    </td>
                {/each}
            </tr>
        {/each}
    </table>
   ```

   Usage example:

   ```html
    <script>
        import DataTable from './DataTable.svelte';
        const rows = [
            { name: 'John', age: 64 },
            { name: 'Jane', age: 46 },
        ]
        const columns = [
            { key: 'name' },
            { key: 'age' },
        ]
    </script>

    <DataTable {columns} {rows} let:key let:value>
        {#if key == 'name'}
            <button>{value}</button>
        {:else}
            {value} <!-- Fallback to just the cell content -->
        {/if}
    </DataTable>
   ```

   [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f85e1c99548a4a65ac5de44e57c1d8af?version=3.48.0)

Answer (score 1):

If it's pure HTML (no Svelte-specific code, just raw HTML), you can use the `@html` directive:

```html
<script> 
  const columnsMockExample = [{name: 'Column 1', html: '<div>Inner HTML example</div>' }] 
</script>

{#each columnsMockExample as example}
  {@html example.html}
{/each}
```

Docs: https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-html

If there's Svelte components or click handlers etc in there, that doesn't work though. In that case you need to rewrite the code using components and slots (https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-slot) and/or the `svelte:component` tag (https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-component) - how exactly depends on what your goal is.